# trying to copy actual file to another path using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make the py file who's running this code startup with computer copying itself to startup path

```
from shutil import copyfile
from os import getcwd
from getpass import getuser

src = f"{getcwd()}/test.py"
dst = f"C:/Users/{getuser()}/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup"
copyfile(src, dst)
```

but it isn't working.

```
PS D:\projects\programming> & C:/Users/vinic/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe d:/projects/programming/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\projects\programming\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Users\vinic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 256, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/vinic/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup'
PS D:\projects\programming>
```

Comment: are you sure the destination directory exists?

Comment: also use `os.getenv("APPDATA")` to get to the "Roaming" directory without assuming C:\users and all

Comment: guyssss, I was wrong in the 6 line, I didn't write the archive name on the final of the path!
Now it's right:

from shutil import copyfile
from os import getcwd
from getpass import getuser

src = f"{getcwd()}/test.py"
dst = f"C:/Users/{getuser()}/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup/test.py"
copyfile(src, dst)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yess

Answer (score 1):

`copyfile` needs a filename, not a directory name.

Just do `shutil.copy(src,dst)`

`copy` checks if the destination is a directory first, like the classical `cp` command.

To improve from your original code, here are a few more suggestions

- no need to prepend `getpwd` to the source file, since you're not using any `chdir` afterwards. If needed, rather use `os.path.abspath()`
- use `APPDATA` environment variable to get to `Roaming` directory.

like that:

```
src = "test.py"
dst = os.path.join(os.getenv("APPDATA"),"Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup")
shutil.copy(src,dst)
```

if you *absolutely* need `copyfile` (which is sometimes better because it doesn't copy attributes of the source, like read-only, an alternative would be:

```
shutil.copyfile(src,os.path.join(dst,os.path.basename(src)))
```

it rebuilds destination file path, and allows to use `copyfile`

Comment: imho using `pathlib.Path` instead of `os.path.join` would further improve the original code

Comment: yeah, you can edit the answer if you want (but make sure it works !). I'm os.path fluent but not pathlib fluent, as I have a lot of 2.7 legacy code at my company :)

Comment: Mann thankss❤️ @Jean-FrançoisFabre